# How to use passport-ldapauth npm

Tags: node.js, ldap, passport.js

Can someone help me what I am doing wrong in my below code. None of the console message is getting printed. I am looking for a ldap client npm which supports in node v4.1.1

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

// Credentials from the free LDAP test server by forumsys
// More info at: http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/
var OPTS = {
    server: {
        url: 'ldap://IP:PORT',
        bindDn: <admin username>,
        bindCredentials: <admin password>,
        usernameField: <username>,
        passwordField: <pass>
    }
};

passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));

passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}, function (err, user, info) {
    console.log(info);
    if (err) {
        console.log(err); // will generate a 500 error
    }
    // Generate a JSON response reflecting authentication status
    if (!user) {
        console.log("authentication failed");
    }
    console.log("authentication succeeded");
})
```

Comment: and how you use this in end point / routers? Can you show me your code for endpoint

Comment: ldapjs is not working in node v4.1.1. Below is my code. I am trying to achieve the same using passport npm. Let me know if I am doing something wrong in it.
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:1389'
});

client.bind('cn=root', 'secret', function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('authenticated');
  }
});

client.unbind(function(err) {
});

Comment: Are you looking for LDAP client like you said, or LDAP authentication strategy for [Passport](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate)? Because `passport-ldapauth` is the latter and cannot be used as generic LDAP client. Use `ldapjs`, it does work in v4.1.1 if you don't need TLS. If you need, use the unpublished version from Github.